# Cant looping data from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Hello I am having a problem to retrieve data from firebase. I do looping to retrieve my data but it is not working properly. **User ID** and **Query** can normally run on looping, but **Data Value** is not working properly, **Data Value** should be displayed alternately like **User ID** and **Query** but it was not like that, they run like this [pitcure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NnI8.jpg).

This is my code :

```
int a = 0;
values.forEach((key, values) {
  // print ('Test $a : ' + values['pengguna_uid'].toString());
  // print('Test $a : ' + values[a]['pengguna_uid'].toString());

  String userUid = values['pengguna_uid'];
  print('User ID $a : ' + userUid);
  final databaseUserNama = FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .reference()
      .child('users')
      .child(userUid);

  print('Query $a : ' + databaseUserNama.toString());

  databaseUserNama.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    print('Value $a : ' + snapshot.value.toString());

    setState(() {
      userNama = snapshot.value["pengguna_nama"];                    
    });
    // print('User Nama $a : ' + userNama);
  });

  listNama.add(userNama.toString());
  lists.add(values);
  a++;
});
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you share demo(not real data) of your firebase database structure? It would help in understanding how you have structured your data and how you want to retrieve and loop on it.

Comment: Hello thank you for the response, this is my database structure : [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11XlWoz15AtpKTVMZEgE2Q0oYxR7HtdRt)